# Что за сертификат? Как от него избавиться?

Tags: windows, windows-10, сертификат, rdp

При подключении к удалённому рабочему столу, на удалённом генерируется сертификат с именем

> S-1-5-21-183##3189-3615##5645-3821##652-1001/b73cf###-e0cb-414####ea-ab21ffa8a2b2/login.windows.net/c1c942f3-2##49af-98b4-5f34bba3c5df/y.k###kov@so##.ru

(некоторые символы заменены на решетки), действует до 2048 и назначение "Вход со смарт-картой". 
Локально такой содержится в Сертификаты/Личное и Сертификаты/Local NonRemovable.
Что это за серт? И как сделать чтобы он не генерился удалённо?

`y.k###kov@so##.ru` - это моя корпоративная почта. к удалённому компьютеру кроме меня подключается множество других пользователей, но лишь мой оставляет там этот сомнительный сертификат, который есть у меня локально и при удалении его и перезапуске - он снова появляется

Comment: Попробуйте начать с изучения самого сертификата со страницы издателя http://www.soft.ru/. Возможно поможет.

Comment: Подключены ли к компьютеру какие-либо устройства для чтения электронных ключей?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, компьютер офисный, вероятно да - подключен. e-mail в названии серта это моя корпоративная почта

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, нужна ещё какая-то информация, которая поможет определить что за сертификат ?

Comment: Попробуйте в параметрах RDP подключения выбрать Локальные ресурсы - Подробнее, и снять галку "Смарт карты" - перестанет ли сертификат появляться на удаленном сервере?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, перестал! Сам я не смог найти эту настройку. Спасибо) Напишите ответ, чтобы я мог отметить его верным. Видимо вы поняли что это за сертификат)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RDP в Windows поддерживает перенаправление некоторых типов устройств, т.е., при заходе на удаленный сервер, пользователь может взаимодействовать с устройствами с локального компьютера. К перенаправляемым устройствам относятся и [считыватели электронных ключей](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/smart-cards/smart-card-and-remote-desktop-services) (в интерфейсе Windows это называется смарт-картами).

Многие драйвера считывателей настроены таким образом, что при появлении электронного ключа они автоматически регистрируют сертификат в системе. Чтобы предотвратить появление сертификата на удаленном сервере, нужно в параметрах RDP подключения выбрать "Локальные ресурсы - Подробнее", и снять галку с пункта "Смарт карты".

[image: rdp parameters]

Comment: удивительно то, что у моих коллег эта галочка стоит и никакого сертификата у них нет.

Comment: @sevnight На самом деле, ничего удивительного, у них просто нет установленных устройств для считывания смарт-карт. Сравните конфигурацию и набор установленных программ на вашем компьютере и любом другом, и найдите чем они отличаются (начать можно с раздела "Устройства чтения смарт-карт" в диспетчере устройств)